# Allow only letters and spaces and capitalise each word

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input

I need to only allow letters to be typed, and I also need to capitalise the first letter of each word using javascript. I have the first bit working on keypress, I want the second working onblur, but I can't get it to work. It works ok if I use it on its own though. I've tried a bunch of things but I must be missing something small, I just can't figure out what it is.

HTML

```
<tr>
<td>
<input type="text" name="first_names" onkeypress="return isAlfa(event)" onblur="toTitleCase()">
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="last_names" onkeypress="return isAlfa(event)" onblur="toTitleCase()">
</td>
</tr>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
function isAlfa(evt) {
    evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
    if (charCode > 32 && (charCode < 65 || charCode > 90) && (charCode < 97 || charCode > 122)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

function toTitleCase(str)
{
    return str.replace(/\w\S*/g, function(txt){return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();});
}
```

Please assist

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to reassign the value of the input, e.g. like `onblur="this.value = toTitleCase(this.value)"`:

```js
function isAlfa(evt) {
  evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
  var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
  if (charCode > 32 && (charCode < 65 || charCode > 90) && (charCode < 97 || charCode > 122)) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}

function toTitleCase(str) {
  return str.replace(/\w\S*/g, function(txt) {
    return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();
  });
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="first_names" onkeypress="return isAlfa(event)" onblur="this.value = toTitleCase(this.value)">
```